# Why does pd.to_datetime not take the year into account?

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched for 2 hours but can't find an answer for this that works.
I have this dataset I'm working with and I'm trying to find the latest date, but it seems like my code is not taking the year into account. Here are some of the dates that I have in the dataset.

| Date |
| --- |
| 01/09/2023 |
| 12/21/2022 |
| 12/09/2022 |
| 11/19/2022 |

Here's a snippet from my code

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

st.write(df['Date'].max())
```

`st.write` gives me 12/21/2022 as the output instead of 01/09/2023 as it should be. So it seems like the code is not taking the year into account and just looking at the month and date.

I tried changing the format to
`df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: After calling `pd.to_datetime()`, print the datatype of that column to make sure it is an actual date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) allows you to designate column for conversion into dates, let `test.csv` content be

```
Date
01/09/2023
12/21/2022
12/09/2022
11/19/2022
```

then

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=["Date"])
print(df['Date'].max())
```

gives output

```
2023-01-09 00:00:00
```

Explanation: I provide list of names of columns holding dates, which then `read_csv` parses.

*(tested in pandas 1.5.2)*

Comment: thanks for your answer. The issue with this is that it displays the time, which I don't want. And then when I try to graph the data it displays all the dates in between the dates in my dataset.